# How to return the full date/time object in SuiteQL?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql, netsuite-rest-api

I am using the Rest API to run SuiteQL, something like the following:

```
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <> \
--header 'Prefer: transient' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING' \
--data-raw '{
    "q": "SELECT * from customer limit 10"
}'
```

Now I noticed that there are fields like dateLastModified that is type `timestamp`, but in the return result, there's only the date part - "08/12/2023" for example.`

How do I force the API to ALWAYS return the full date time object for timestamp type?

Sometimes I need to write dynamic queries without knowing which columns are timestamp format
so using a function like `SELECT TO_CHAR(dateLastModified, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as c FROM customer`
doesn't always work for me.